Can i solve the following equation by taking the following substitutions of known symbolic functions?
I have the following set of equations:
\begin{align}
    k\, n\, d_{rz}^{(n-1)}\, \frac{\partial d_{rz}}{\partial z} &= \rho \left( \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}v_r + \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}v_z \right) \label{eq:first_equation_nn} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    k \left(n\, d_{rz}^{(n-1)} \frac{\partial d_{rz}}{\partial r} + \frac{d_{rz}^n}{r} \right) &= \rho \left( \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}v_r + \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}v_z \right) \label{eq:second_equation_nn}
\end{align}
I want to solve these for k and n. For $d_{rz}$, $\frac{\partial d_{rz}}{\partial z}$, $\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}$, $v_r$, $\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}$, $v_z$, $\frac{\partial d_{rz}}{\partial r}$, $\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}$ i already have symbolic solutions. For example:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r} = \frac{3 \mathit{v_0} \cot\! \left(\alpha \right) r \left(\frac{2 \mathit{R_0}^{2} \cot\left(\alpha \right)}{3}+z \left(r-\frac{2 \mathit{R_0}}{3}\right)\right) {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{3 r z}{\mathit{R_0} \left(z-\mathit{R_0} \cot\left(\alpha \right)\right)}}}{\mathit{R_0} \left(z-\mathit{R_0} \cot\! \left(\alpha \right)\right)^{3}}
\end{align}
Whereas $v_0, \alpha, R_0, \rho$ are known constants. $r$ and $z$ are variables. So all these expressions can be considered functions of $r$ and $z$.
These expressions get longer and more complex, which makes it virtually impossible to solve the 2 equations by direct substitution of the expressions (Tried here Mathematica and Maple so far).
I have come up with the following idea however - substitution of known symbolic expressions with simple letters, solving for these new simplified equationsvand then substituting back the initial symbolic solutions in the simplifed solutions. This looks like this:
Step 1 - Rewriting the equations:
\begin{align}
k\, n\, x^{n -1} y &= u
\end{align}
\begin{align}
k \left(n\, x^{n -1} \,l + \frac{x^n}{r} \right) &= v 
\end{align}
Step 2 - Solving these equations for $k$ and $n$ in the simplified form:
\begin{align}
k = \frac{-r \left( l u - v y \right)}{e^{ - \frac{\ln(x) u x}{r \left( l u - v y \right)} } \cdot y}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
n = \frac{-u x}{r \left( l u - v y \right)} 
\end{align}
Step 3 - Substituting back the known solutions:
\begin{align}
x = d_{rz}
\end{align}\begin{align}
y = \frac{\partial d_{rz}}{\partial z}
\end{align}\begin{align}
u = \rho \left( \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}v_r + \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}v_z \right)
\end{align}\begin{align}
l = \frac{\partial d_{rz}}{\partial r}
\end{align}\begin{align}
v = \rho \left( \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}v_r + \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}v_z \right)
\end{align}
Step 4 - Simplification of expressions for $k$ and $n$
\begin{align}
k = ...
\end{align}\begin{align}
n = ...
\end{align}
$k$ and $n$ being functions of $r$ and $z$ like all other expressions thus far.
I will not mention now the results as i believe this is beyong the scope and they are extremly long. I think by now you understand my methodology.
I'd like to know from you if what i have done is correct from a mathematical point of view. I am unsure and I would much appreciate the opinion of someone with more exprience!
Thanks in advance,

Any help would be much appreciated!
